# What are real time use cases of relative locator in Selenium 4?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Selenium 4 alpha release has `Relative Locator` which helps to identify locators around a locator like above, below, toLeftOf, toRightOf, near of an element.

I could understand it but I did not get what is actual usage of it. In which situation it is going to be helpful? Which kind of all problems it is going to solve? What are its real time use cases?

Can someone please shade some lights on Relative Locator usage?

Answer (score 1):

This can be used to check the page layout, if the elements appears in the correct order in the UI. You can see uses example in [RelativeLocatorsTests in github](https://github.com/angiejones/selenium-relative-locators/blob/master/src/test/java/books/RelativeLocatorsTests.java)

Screenshot from https://automationbookstore.dev/

[image]

Today if you want to check the the book "Java For Testers" is under "Test Automation in the Real World" and left to "Advanced Selenium in Java", you need to locate those 3 books, get their coordinates and do a calculation. Something like

```
WebElement javaForTesters = driver.findElement(By.id("pid5"));
WebElement testAutomation = driver.findElement(By.id("pid1"));
WebElement advancedSelenium = driver.findElement(By.id("pid6"));

assertTrue(javaForTesters.getX() == testAutomation.getX() && javaForTesters.getY() > testAutomation.getY());
assertTrue(javaForTesters.getY() == testAutomation.getY() && javaForTesters.getX() < testAutomation.getX());
```

With relative locators you can do

```
String id = driver.findElement(withTagName("li")
            .toLeftOf(By.id("pid6"))
            .below(By.id("pid1")))
            .getAttribute("id");

assertEquals(id, "pid5");
```

Which is shorter and easier to understand.